# Perl's rpm version differs from "perl -v"

Tags: perl, centos7, rpm

I work on CentOS 7 and it seems I have a problem with perl.
I need perl at least 5.10 for a project.

When i :

```
perl -v
```

I get a message describing a perl v5.8.9 but when i

```
rpm -qa | grep perl 5-
```

I get a :

```
perl-5.16.3-292.el7.x86_64
```

Back.

I thought that rpm would install this 5.16.3 version but it does not. How do I do it ?

Comment: You probably have multiple perls installed and 5.8 is higher up on the $PATH

Comment: Perl 5 is on version 34 now. You might want something newer than version 16 which almost a decade old.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try running `which perl`.

You probably have multiple installed, and your path is determining which one you get.

A fairly common split is to have a `/usr/bin/perl` which is your 'system' perl  and installed via your package manager, and have another, newer perl installed by downloading and building it into `/usr/local/bin`.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `perlbrew`. You can install it by the following commands:

- `curl -L https://install.perlbrew.pl | bash`
- Initialize:
  `perlbrew init`
- See what is available: `perlbrew available`

Then do switch to different perl version by doing the command:

- `perlbrew swith perl-5.16.3`
- `perl -v`

Comment: I really think your solution could work but sadly my company policy doesn't allow access to the website